# jdbc how can I make sure that 2 rows are unique together

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have an insert clause and 2 columns which are named my_id and stream_id, I would like it so that each pair of (my_id,stream_id) is unique. For example my_id is a users personal unique id and it is always the same and stream_id correspond to different posts. For example if my_id is 4 and a stream_id is 8 then you can insert however since that is now in the database you can not do another insert on that same stream_id of 8. Here is my jdbc code

```
int stream_id= Integer.parseInt(requestData.get("stream_id"));
int my_id= Integer.parseInt(requestData.get("my_id"));
       String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO reputation"
        + "(stream_id,my_id) VALUES"
        + "(?,?)";

    dbConnection = DB.getConnection();
    preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    preparedStatement.setInt(1, stream_id);
    preparedStatement.setInt(2, my_id);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Just to clarify I simply want to make sure that I have unique pairs in the database if I have a my_id of 5 and a stream_id of 9 then I should reject another pair of 5 and 9. The int variables already have those values I just do not know how to check if I have those pairs in the database; if I don't then continue with the insertion otherwise stop the inserts.

Comment: Add a unique key to the database - it should be the job of the RMDBS to ensure data integrity.

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index_name ON reputation(stream_id,my_id)

Comment: Oh ok I am using mysql I know about having unique keys but this is 2 pairs which should make a unique key. I will look into it further.

Comment: Perfect @Lawrence that sounds exactly of what is needed will see how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a unique key in a database. If you want to handle at application site perhaps you could use Hibernate or JPA or JDO.